# Gradle sync error in Android Studio, could not find method android()

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've just installed the latest Android Studio on to a new PC, and tried importing an existing project from my Git repo.  However I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(91, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments 
[build_5rpi8n4wxkti5snnxm1rtlcug$_run_closure7@4154e46b] 
on root project 'my_project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I've tried updating the module settings to use the latest Gradle version, but that didn't help.  Any ideas on what that error means or where to look?  I guess the org.gradle.api.Project class is missing an android method, meaning it's the wrong version or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed this myself! It turns out that Android Studio had added a section to the main build.gradle file that shouldn't be there...

At the bottom of the file was:

```
android {
   /** couple of lines **/
}
```

Deleting that entire block has fixed my build. I'll leave the question up here, maybe it helps someone else having the same problem.

Comment: You just saved my life. Do you know where that came from at all?